# How to bubble events on a component subcomponent chain with Vue js 2?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have my vue application using:

component-parent component that is made of component-child

inside component-parent I have buttons, when someone click a button I want to emit an event in order to be handled by vue and passed to another component

What I did so far:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
        itemSelectedListener: function(item){
            console.log('itemSelectedListener', item);
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('component-child', {
    template: ' <span  v-on:click="chooseItem(pty )" >Button  </span>',
    methods: {
        chooseItem: function(pty){
            console.log(pty);
            this.$emit('itemSelected', {
                'priority' : pty
            });
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('component-parent', {
    template: '<component-child  v-for="q in items" ></component-child>'
});
```

HTML:

```
<component-parent v-on:itemSelected="itemSelectedListener"  ></component-parent>
```

It reaches my `console.log(pty);` line but it seems that `this.$emit('itemSelected'` wont get through:

```
console.log('itemSelectedListener', item); // this is not going to be called...
```

an hint?

should I bubble up the event from child->parent->Vue-instance? ( I also tried that but with no success)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is one issue with your `component-parent` template as it tries to render multiple child components. Vue usually requires a single root div inside components therefore you need to wrap it in a div or other tag.

```
<div>
    <component-child  v-for="q in items"></component-child>
</div>
```

A second thing to point out is that you emit an event from a child component which is 2 levels down and you listen to it in the root.

```
Root //but you listen to the event up here 1 level above
 Component 1 //you should listen to the event here
  Component 2 //your try to emit it from here
```

You have 2 options here. Either emit from `component-child` listen to that event in `component-parent` then propagate that event upwards. Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bjqwh74t/29/

The second option would be to register a global so called `bus` which is an empty vue instance that you can use for such cases when you want communication between non child-parent components. Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bjqwh74t/30/

Usually between parent and child components you use the events directly by emitting from child and listening in parent with `v-on:event-name="handler"` but for cases where you have more levels between components you use the second approach.

Doc link for the first case: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events

Doc link for the second case: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

PS: prefer using kebab-case for event names which means you write with `-` instead of capital letters. Writing with capital letters can result in weird situations where your event is not caught in the root.

Comment: The doc link for the second case no longer exists. Do you have an updated link?

Comment: [More on event buses here](https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/intro-to-vue-js/tabs)

Comment: I would even say in other words: the events in Vue do not work like the native events in a browser. Events in Vue are as callbacks on the parent, and $emit in child is just a call of parent's callback. I'm right?
P.S.I rummaged through all the documentation in Vue, but this is not clearly stated anywhere. It seems to me that they confuse newbies with the word "event".

Comment: I found a good working link about this:

https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2020/01/06/handling-events-vue-js/

"Custom events" and "Event bus" sections

Answer (score 22):

For what it's worth you can use the browser's event API. It requires a little more scripting than Vue's built-in stuff, but it also gets you around these bubbling issues (and is about the same amount of code as creating a "bus", as in the accepted answer).

On child component:

```
this.$el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('itemSelected', { detail: { 'priority' : pty }, bubbles: true, composed: true });
```

On parent component, in `mounted` lifecycle part:

```
mounted() {
    this.$el.addEventListener('itemSelected', e => console.log('itemSelectedListener', e.detail));
}
```

Comment: I've seen the Bus suggestion a lot of times - and in use in 3rd party modules, but using a Bus was not the right pattern for me and my use case and would have been a lot of work to get it to work how I wanted.  This is what I wanted, it's obvious now you've said it, but I couldn't think of it.

Comment: regular vue event bind v-bind:itemSelected works too

Comment: There are situations where this is the only solution. I've using Rete framework in Vue project, and Rete uses Vue too, but Rete's Node as Vue components does not have $root and $parent, and native CustomEvents is the only way to pass events up to my application.

But it should be


     this.$el.addEventListener('itemSelected', e => console.log('itemSelectedListener', e.detail));


addEventListener instead of addListener

Comment: This worked for me! simple solution. I used `v-on:itemSelected.native` to make it work. It didn't work without the `.native` suffix.

Comment: Cannot edit but there's a typo for `addListener` which should be `addEventListener`

Comment: Thanks @YamiOdymel I will fix

Answer (score 5):

It's a little bit late but here's how I did it:

component-child:

```
this.$root.$emit('foobar',{...});
```

component-parent:

```
this.$root.$on('foobar')
```

Comment: You'll also need to call `this.$root.$off('foorbar', fn)` in `beforeDestroy()` or `destroy()` to avoid a memory leak,  The fn variable must match the value in `this.$root.$on('foorbar', fn)` so the callback function cannot be an anonymous function.

Comment: Note: `$on` and `$off` has been **deprecated** since Vue 3.0

Comment: Downvote due to deprecation.

Answer (score 4):

In your child component, simply use `$emit` to send an event to the `$root` like this:

```
v-on:click="$root.$emit('hamburger-click')"
```

Then, in your parent component (eg: "App"), setup the listener in the Vue `mounted` lifecycle hook like this:

```
  export default {
    <snip...>
    mounted: function() {
      this.$root.$on('hamburger-click', function() {
        console.log(`Hamburger clicked!`);
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little surprised nobody suggested using an event bus component.  It is a fairly common pattern in heavily decoupled systems to have a shared event bus, and then use it to link multiple disconnected components together pub/sub style.

```
//eventbus.js
import Vue from 'vue'

export const EventBus = new Vue()
```

Once you have one, it's simple to publish events from any place

```
// component1.js
import { EventBus } from '@/services/eventbus'
...
EventBus.$emit('do-the-things')
```

And listen to them from somewhere else.

```
// component2.js
import { EventBus } from '@/services/eventbus'
...
EventBus.$on('do-the-things', this.doAllTheThings)
```

Note that the two components do not know anything about each other, and they don't really need to care how or why the event was raised.

There are some potentially undesirable side effects of this approach.  Event names do need to be globally unique so that you don't confuse your app.  You'll also potentially be channeling every single event through a single object unless you do something more sophisticated.  You can do the cost / benefit analysis on your own app source to see if it's right for you.

Comment: event bus is a good solution for more complex components hierarchies. But this is not about the question topic.

Comment: @slf FYI, Cristi Jora's already mentioned event bus in his answer.

Comment: This is a global pub/sub used as a mediator, in the long term this can evolve into a god object and make components be coupled to the mediator, or at least its interface.

In my opinion Vue should offer Event Bubbling.

Comment: The lack of automatic event bubbling in Vue is the most frustrating of its limitations...

Answer (score 3):

Create a [custome directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) for bubbling and use it in the child component.

Sample directive:

```
// Add this to main.ts when initializing Vue
Vue.directive('bubble', {
  bind(el, { arg }, {context, componentInstance}) {
    if (!componentInstance || !context || !arg) {
      return;
    }
    
    // bubble the event to the parent
    componentInstance.$on(v, context.$emit.bind(context, arg));
  }
});
```

Child component can use that directive to emit through the parent component (i switched to kabob case and shorthand for event).

```
<!-- template for component-parent -->
<component-child v-bubble:item-selected  v-for="q in items"></component-child>

<!-- usage of component-parent -->
<component-parent @:item-selected="itemSelectedListener"></component-parent>
```

Including my full bind directive below. It allows bubbling multiple events.

```
<!--------------------
 * A few examples 
--------------------->
<!-- bubble single event -->
<child v-bubble:click/>
<child v-bubble:_.click/>
<child v-bubble="'click'"/>
<child v-bubble:any-costume-event-will-work/>

<!-- bubble: click, focus, blur -->
<child v-bubble:_.click.focus.blur/> 
<child v-bubble="'click, focus, blur'"/>

<!-- prefixed bubbling: click, focus, blur as child-click, child-focus, child-blur -->
<child v-bubble:child.click.focus.blur/> 
<child v-bubble:child="'click, focus, blur'"/>
```

```
Vue.directive('bubble', {
        bind(el, { value, arg: prefix = '', modifiers }, {context, componentInstance}) {
  const events = value && value.trim() ? value.split(',') : Object.keys(modifiers);
    if (!events.length && prefix) {
      events.push(prefix);
      prefix = '';
    } else if(prefix) {
      prefix = prefix === '_' ? '' : prefix += '-';
    }

    if (!componentInstance || !context || !events.length) {
      return;
    }

    events.forEach((v: string) => {
      v = v.trim();
      const eventName = `${prefix}${v}`;
      const bubble = context.$emit.bind(context, eventName);
      componentInstance.$on(v, bubble);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I see that this solution is downvoted, but there isn't any comment as to why. It does seem very verbose, especially in comparison to an event bus, or even native JS event bubbling . While it may work, its not the kind of use of a custom directive that I would expect. What are the advantages of using this solution?

Comment: @orionrush This simply creates a short hand for option 1 of the accepted answer (emit from component-child listen to that event in component-parent then propagate that event upwards). If you look at the first code snippet, that's exactly what's happening. The more verbose version is handling all sorts of things for completeness. Native event bubbling won't work for custom events. And the event bus won't work when you have multiple components of the same type with children emitting the same events. All components of that type will pick up the event and update when only the ancestor should.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the insight. I think these ideas could be flushed out in the answer itself, specifically how the children of multiple components of the same type emitting events will be undifferentiated, and how your solution with a custom directive addresses this. Probably a more advanced solution than some were looking for/understood.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. Bubbling is part of the CustomEvent Specification. https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-customevent

Vue should allow for event bubbling

Comment: This is a great idea and works for Vue 2, but unfortunately, it doesn't work for Vue 3.