# Root Vue instance not receiving events

Tags: vue.js

I cannot receive any events from a child component in the root Vue instance.

I have a simple child component which emits a 'hello' event when clicked or mounted:

```
<template>
  <div v-on:click="clicked"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ChildComponent',
  mounted() {
    this.$emit('hello');
  },
  methods: {
    clicked() {
      this.$emit('hello');
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

In my root Vue instance I've tried everything to receive the event, but none of the handlers seem to be receiving the event. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
const comp = () => import('./components/SomeVueWhichHasChild.vue');

const v = new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(comp, {
    on: {
      hello: () => {
        console.log('VUE INSTANCE HELLO');
      }
    },
    nativeOn: {
      hello: () => {
        console.log('NATIVE HELLO');
      }
    }
  }),
});
v.$on('hello', () => {
  console.log('ON HELLO');
});

v.$mount('#app');
```

Comment: Are you sure the `clicked()` method in the child component is being called? The div is empty so I assume it wouldn't have any size; how are you able to click it?

Comment: Yes this was just sample code for this post. For example, ChildComponent's parent can receive the event and emit it to its parent, and so on and so forth until it reaches the root.

In my case I'm writing a plugin and cannot control the hierarchy of components. I need to emit an event from my plugin's component to the root Vue instance. The answer I provided is working well for me thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a dup of:

[How to bubble events on a component subcomponent chain with Vue js 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029150/how-to-bubble-events-on-a-component-subcomponent-chain-with-vue-js-2)

Only a direct parent of a component can listen for events. I used native JS events instead:

```
this.$el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('hello', {
  detail: { ... },
  bubbles: true,
  composed: true
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Decade Moon said, your div should have some content to be able to be clickable. For example:

```
<div v-on:click="clicked">Test content</div>
```

You can check my demo on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/ydbegw)

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear. Your example works because your ChildComponent is a direct child of the root Vue instance. In my example the root Vue instance's child is "SomeVueWhichHasChild" which may have ChildComponent nested N levels deep.